# I can't hear anyone on skype/mumble

Tags: 14.04, sound, skype, mumble

So recently I've noticed that every time I go on mumble, I can't hear anyone's voice. Mumble has a feature where when someone talks, it lowers the volume, which it does for me, except I do not hear any voice. I have been called by a friend on Skype, and I thought her microphone just didn't work, but turns out it is something wrong with my Linux. I am using Ubuntu/Gnome (combination of the two) 32 bit and I would like help on how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say if you have sound with other software but I guess yes.
Check pulseaudio doing a Skype test call while running  "**sound settings**" and going  in the "**applications**" tab: you should see Skype (or Mumble) with a volume setting   .
But it is better to install **pavucontrol** (pulseaudio volume setting) and look in the "**playback**"  tab : Skype (or mumble) should also appears , adding  a vumeter  .
Look also in "output device" tab : if you use f. i. a usb headphone only for Skype, you can choose it there.